# XML Search and Change in SQL Server XML datatype column

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I would like to update a column of datatype `XML` in a table for all the records in that table.

For example below is the content of XML for a single row:

```
 <assessmentItem xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/apip/apipv1p0/qtiitem/imsqti_v2p2" 
        adaptive="false" identifier="VHXYZ" timeDependent="false" 
        title="ZonesSS" toolName="IBIS Export" toolVersion="1.0">
    <responseDeclaration baseType="identifier" cardinality="single" 
             identifier="VH221999_order_match_choice_list_10.RESPONSE">
        <correctResponse>
            <value>i2</value>
        </correctResponse>
    </responseDeclaration>
    <outcomeDeclaration baseType="float" cardinality="single" identifier="SCORE">
        <defaultValue>
            <value>0</value>
        </defaultValue>
    </outcomeDeclaration>
</assessmentItem>
```

I want to change this to

```
<assessmentItem xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/apip/apipv1p0/qtiitem/imsqti_v2p2"  
       adaptive="false" identifier="VHXYZ" timeDependent="false" title="ZonesSS" 
       toolName="IBIS Export" toolVersion="1.0">
    <responseDeclaration baseType="identifier" cardinality="single" identifier="RESPONSE">
        <correctResponse>
            <value>i2</value>
        </correctResponse>
    </responseDeclaration>
    <outcomeDeclaration baseType="float" cardinality="single" identifier="SCORE">
        <defaultValue>
            <value>0</value>
        </defaultValue>
    </outcomeDeclaration>
</assessmentItem>
```

Basic change is change the value of attribute identifier="RESPONSE" in `<responseDeclation>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [modify method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms187093.aspx) on your XML type column.

```
update [YourTable]
set [XmlColumn].modify('replace value of
    (/assessmentItem/responseDeclaration/@identifier)[1] with "RESPONSE"'
)
where /*your where criteria here*/
```

The above XQuery example assumes your XML schema has only one occurrence of `assessmentItem` and/or `responseDeclaration`

Comment: Thank you . What if we have one more <responseDeclaration> and want to change its "Identifier" value then does the below query works?                update [YourTable] 
set [XmlColumn].modify('replace value of
    (/assessmentItem/responseDeclaration/@identifier)[2] with "RESPONSE"'
)
where /*your where criteria here*/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, you can use SQL Server `replace value of` expression to modify a value in XML data type. It has limitation though, that only a single value can be updated at a time (see the documentation : [replace value of (XML DML) > Arguments > Expression1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675.aspx)).

Another thing to note is that your XML data has default namespace. So you need to tell SQL Server's XQuery about that, for example :

```
declare default element namespace "http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/apip/apipv1p0/qtiitem/imsqti_v2p2";
```

**For demo, consider the following data in XML variable :**

```
declare @xml XML = '<assessmentItem xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/apip/apipv1p0/qtiitem/imsqti_v2p2" 
        adaptive="false" identifier="VHXYZ" timeDependent="false" 
        title="ZonesSS" toolName="IBIS Export" toolVersion="1.0">
    <responseDeclaration baseType="identifier" cardinality="single" 
             identifier="VH221999_order_match_choice_list_10.RESPONSE">
        <correctResponse>
            <value>i2</value>
        </correctResponse>
    </responseDeclaration>
    <outcomeDeclaration baseType="float" cardinality="single" identifier="SCORE">
        <defaultValue>
            <value>0</value>
        </defaultValue>
    </outcomeDeclaration>
</assessmentItem>'
```

**Demo Query :**

```
--value before
;with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/apip/apipv1p0/qtiitem/imsqti_v2p2')
select @xml.value('(/assessmentItem/responseDeclaration/@identifier)[1]','varchar(max)')

--update operation
set @xml.modify('
declare default element namespace "http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/apip/apipv1p0/qtiitem/imsqti_v2p2";
replace value of
    (/assessmentItem/responseDeclaration/@identifier)[1] with "RESPONSE"'
)

--value after
;with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/apip/apipv1p0/qtiitem/imsqti_v2p2')
select @xml.value('(/assessmentItem/responseDeclaration/@identifier)[1]','varchar(max)')
```

**output :** (the top one is the 'value before' and the other is the 'value after')

```
VH221999_order_match_choice_list_10.RESPONSE
RESPONSE
```